# Stack Exchange reputation point concentration indicators

Tags: discussion

I am bad at using the SE query tools: 
Is it possible to estimate some indicators for the concentration of reputation points on Economics.SE (e.g., HHI, Gini, C4)?

If yes, how do these compare with the concentration on other small SE sites or even large SE sites?

---

P.s.: I think there is a lot of randomness in the pointsystem (hot question, early answer, etc.), so I am not claiming that points are indicative of anything.

Comment: what do you mean by concentration of points? Like how many points individual users have for some subject matter? Or how many of the total points on the site are there for some topics?

Comment: @1muflon1 I meant "do the 20% of users with the highest reputation have 99% of all the reputation points on the site?", but with more elaborate indicators as mentioned above. However your idea of "market share of topic/tag [X]" also seems interesting.